# ¿Como importar en base de datos MySQL desde linea de comandos?

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd, importación, línea-de-comandos

Estoy intentando importar una base de datos mas o menos grande (`1Gb`) usando `PHPMyAdmin`.
El proceso es demasiado lento y siempre se corta.

¿Existe alguna forma de importar una base de datos `MySQL` desde la linea de comandos?

Comment: no probaste colocando por ejemplo en la unidad C tu archivo sql y luego desde línea de comandos importarla de este modo: `SOURCE tubase.sql` ?

Comment: @shadow no, pero la respuesta de como hacerlo es bienvenida

Comment: Fijate este link @Marcos https://stackoverflow.com/a/17666279/6388106

Comment: @Juan, desde mi punto de vista tu respuesta no estaba mal del todo ^^, el detalle es que en lugar de usar `>` (exportar), me parece que debería haber sido `<` (importar). Fíjate si podes probarlo y restablecer tu respuesta con esa corrección. Desde ya gracias por tu aporte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#mysqldump-option-examples) pude importar un archivo `sql` directamente en la base de datos.

#### En Linux o Windows `cmd`:

```
$ mysql -u <usuario> -p <nombreBaseDeDatos> < <archivo.sql>
```

Indicando la contraseña (*inseguro*):

```
$ mysql -u <usuario> -p<contraseña> <nombreBaseDeDatos> < <archivo.sql>
```

#### En Windows `Powershell`

```
$ Get-Content <archivo.sql> | mysql -u <usuario> -p <nombreBaseDeDatos>
```

Indicando la contraseña (*inseguro*):

```
$ Get-Content <archivo.sql> | mysql -u <usuario> -p<contraseña> <nombreBaseDeDatos>
```

---

Referencia:

- [Respuesta original SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546797/3791844)
- [Solución Powershell SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148816/3791844)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta que daré no la tengo probada con archivos `.sql` de ese tamaño `1GB` sin embargo te lo comparto

1. Ubica tu archivo `.sql` dentro de la Unidad C por ejemplo con un nombre descriptivo

---

```
C:.
├───backup.sql
```

2. Posterior desde la línea de comandos de tu  `mysql` ejecutas lo siguiente

---

```
mysql -u root -p
password: *******

mysql> SOURCE C:/backup.sql;
```

La consola dependiendo del número de tablas debería estar devolviendo algo similar a lo siguiente

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.10 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 13 rows affected (11.51 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.22 sec)

.................................. more
```

**ACLARACIONES**

1. Si el archivo `.sql` ya contiene en su estructura las declaraciones de:

   CREATE DATABASE

y

```
USE tuBaseDatos
```

Entonces no es necesario crearla sino simplemente ejecutar dicho comando

2. Si por el contrario la base de datos no existe en el gestor de bases de datos y tampoco existe la declaración en el respaldo `.sql` entonces:

Primero se debe ejecutar

```
CREATE DATABASE TubaseDatos;
```

Y posterior

```
USE TubaseDatos;
```

para que al final ejecutemos

```
SOURCE C:/backup.sql
```

**Referencias**

- [MySQL source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)
- [Importar base de datos desde terminal](https://ed.team/blog/como-importar-una-base-de-datos-mysql-desde-la-terminal)

Comment: ¿Como indico el nombre de la DB?

Comment: si en tu archivo `.sql` ya esta declarado el nombre de la BD entonces el comando  `SOURCE` al ejecutarse la creará también así que de manera explícita no necesitas declararlo @Marcos

Comment: ¿y si no estuviese? seria genial si pudieras agregarlo en tu respuesta

Comment: @Marcos entonces si primero debes crear la BD luego darle al comando use TuBase y ya después el comando que expongo en mi respuesta