# Cronjob mysql no se ejecuta en servidor linux de easyname

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, crontab, cronjobs

Me encuentro con un problema un poco peculiar, hace un tiempo adquirí un dominio de la página web easyname, que contiene una base de datos y demás elementos. En este dominio tengo una opción para añadir **cronjobs** de tal manera que se me ejecuten en el tiempo que yo desee.
Cuando hago cronjobs de hola mundo funcionan perfectamente pero a la hora de hacer el siguiente comando:

```
mysql --user="miusuario" --database="mibasededatos"
--password="micontraseña" < /data/web/e101919/check_sql/comprobacion.sql
```

El cron no ejecuta nada.
He probado a volcar el resultado en un `txt` y no vuelca nada, por lo que supongo que da un error.

**comprobacion.sql** contiene una sentencia que elimina usuarios que no han verificado su cuenta cada cierto tiempo.
Lo curioso es que cuando accedo al servidor mediante una conexión `ssh` y ejecuto el comando que he mencionado antes, lo ejecuta y funciona correctamente.

He dado todos los permisos a la carpeta y sigue pasando lo mismo.
Agradecería que me indicaran el fallo y como arreglarlo, o si no alternativas para poder eliminar periódicamente los usuarios que no han verificado su cuenta de la base de datos.

Comment: Intenta hacerlo [así](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/225818/16597)

Answer (score -1):

Personalmente no veo adecuado añadir tus credenciales en más ficheros de los estrictamente pertinentes, por seguridad.

He buscado algo por internet, y aquí mismo, en SO, en su versión inglesa, @fancyPants proporciona una solución, creo, mucho más adecuada (para MySQL), que, quizás te sirva de ayuda, creando un evento programado mediante SQL:

[Run a mySQL query as a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196613/run-a-mysql-query-as-a-cron-job)